# How to reload screen after API call in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to reload entire `ViewController` after successfully deleting record.

**1.** I tried below solution but it is not working.

```
self.view setNeedsDisplay
```

**2.** and I tried following solution also

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Root_View")
```

It is working but it is hiding back `button` on top and **disabling** click events

Comment: You should have a callback in the form of a completion block which then updates the UI. As for the UI it depends what exactly you're updating e.g. UILabels, UIImageViews? etc

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't reload entire View Controller, just reload elements on your UI that should be reloaded. Propably you are doing something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    updateUI()
}

func updateUI() {
    label1.text = "aa"
    label2.text = "bb"
}
```

So just call your `updateUI()` function again after fetching data from API

Answer (score 1):

Can't see your code, but you might be using wrong thread.
Try this

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      updateUIFunctions()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

`view.setNeedsDisplay()`

It may help you..

Also, you can call `viewDidLoad()` in **Swift 3** And in **Objective C** `[self viewDidLoad];`

If you are in same screen and updating it from being in it then by calling viewDidLoad() should work, but if you are in another screen and want to update any previous screen then you should use protocol or block to update the previous viewController.

Comment: Well, have you tried @Michal's Code? if its get worked then fine else try to  set every declared property as `week` reference, then `viewDidLod()` should must work.

Comment: @Ragini see my updated answer and what you are looking for and where? let us know..

Comment: do not call viewDidLoad, it's view lifecycle!